# Multiple Objects in Python

Tags: python

I want to create two objects of a class. Using these two objects i want to input some numbers into a list which is a member of the class. After inputting data it will display the content of the list. Simple code. But the output was not which i want.

```
class Demo:
    arr = []
    n = 0
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.n=s
    def fill(self):
        print("Enter elements in array ")
        for i in range(self.n):
            x=input()
            self.arr.append(x)
    def show(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            print(self.arr[i])



obj1 = Demo(5)
obj2 = Demo(3)
obj1.fill()
obj2.fill()
print("Data from first Object")
obj1.show()
print("Data from second object")
obj2.show()
```

Comment: How does the program behavior differ from what's expected?

Comment: You seem to have forgot your output when you run this

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
def __init__(self,s):
    self.n=s
    self.arr = []
```

By creating `arr` in the body of the class (rather than in the initializer), it becomes part of the class itself - shared by all instances.